# R Version 4.0.3 64 64 Bit Crashing on Windows 10

Tags: r, windows

I was running `R` 4.0.3 64 bit on Windows 10 which was working fine, the Last night I open it through `Rstudio` and got the attached screenshot. I tried to open ordinary `R` but it crashes almost immediately. [image: Rstudio interface]

I will not want to use a lower version because I have run some simulations with seeds that running a lower version will not reproduce what I had before.

What can I do to correct this?

Comment: Have you tried to un- and reinstall R and RStudio completely as the message suggests? To easily reinstall all your packages afterwards, you should follow this blogpost when doing so: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/05/upgrade-r-without-losing-your-packages/

Comment: I also had the same problem. Even after uninstalling all versions of R from my machine, and then installing only 4.0.3, it was still refusing to start. And it just started this morning.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Any version above 4.0.2 seems to only want to run 32bit version of R. Is your Windows 10 version under enterprise/administrative control?